# API вместо DB ? (Laravel/Yii2)

Tags: база-данных, api, laravel, yii2

Нужно сделать `web-сервис` и приложение под `Android` с одинаковым функционалом и общей базой данных. Как я понимаю, нужно создать сервер, предоставляющий доступ к базе данных через `API`. Так ли это, или существуют другие варианты? Существуют ли готовые решения на `Yii2` или `Laravel`?

Comment: На самом деле, API уже готово. Нужно подключить к нему сайт. Существуют ли готовые решения? Как правильно это реализовать на фреймворке? Сделать модели, работающие с API вместо базы данных?

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрите вариант Rest API (Slim и т.п.) и фронтенд на JS (Angular и т.п.)
Либо разработка на Yii/Laravel и отдельно RestApi для мобильного клиента.

Comment: Запросы к API в любом случае необходимо будет делать на стороне сервера?

Comment: Нет, запросы к API выполняются через HTTP POST/GET. На стороне сервера их обрабатывает PHP-скрипт или иная логика, реализующая доступ к данным.

Comment: Если при попытке авторизации на моем сайта напрямую посылать запрос к API через js - это будет не правильно?

Comment: Почему? Вполне себе правильно. Если нужна большая безопасность - используйте https.

Comment: Но, в таком случае придется дублировать отправку запроса к API в клиентской и в серверной части?

Comment: Вам стоит рассматривать клиентскую и серверную часть как различные системы. В этом суть API. Вместо клиента в браузере на JS может быть что угодно, что может работать с сервером по его протоколам. Код на сервере будет работать с базой данных и реализовывать валидацию, а код на клиенте будет отображать интерфейс и по необходимости делать запросы к серверной части за данными.